# Cómo obtener el valor maximo de un objeto

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
 "resultados": [
        {
            "dateTime": "2021-08-13",
            "value": "12"
        },
        {
            "dateTime": "2021-08-14",
            "value": "85"
        },
        {
            "dateTime": "2021-08-15",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "dateTime": "2021-08-16",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "dateTime": "2021-08-17",
            "value": "12000"
        }
```

Me gustaría obtener el valor maximo y el valor de su fecha (dateTime), es decir, lo que quiero que me devuevla es:

```
valor maximo: "dateTime": "2021-08-17", "value": "12000"
```

He probado con lo siguiente, pero solo consigo el valor maximo, y quiero además del maximo su fecha

```
 const groups = this.ativitiesStep.map(item => (item.value));
 const leght = groups.map(set => set.length);
const max =Math.max(...groups)
```

Alguien me podría orinetar como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Implementa un ordenamiento ascendente con `sort()` ordenando por la propiedad `value`, luego el último elemento del arreglo será el mayor. También puedes usar `find()` y obtener el objeto donde la propiedad `value` coincida con el valor máximo que ya encontraste.

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente ordena el array de manera descendente con el método [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) y luego el primer valor del array será el elemento mayor. Será un objeto que contendrá tanto la fecha como el valor.

Te adjunto una posible solución.

```js
objeto = {
  resultados: [
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-13',
      value: '12'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-14',
      value: '85'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-15',
      value: '0'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-16',
      value: '0'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-17',
      value: '12000'
    }
  ]
}

const resultadosOrdenados = objeto.resultados.sort((a,b) =>{
  return Number.parseInt(b.value) - Number.parseInt(a.value)
}) 

console.log('Array Ordenado: ',resultadosOrdenados)
console.log('Mayor Valor: ', resultadosOrdenados[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes tomar el valor máximo (parte que a has hecho) y filtrar el objeto con ese valor:
`objeto.resultados.filter(x=>x.value==maxValue)`

```js
objeto = {
  resultados: [
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-13',
      value: '12'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-14',
      value: '85'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-15',
      value: '0'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-16',
      value: '0'
    },
    {
      dateTime: '2021-08-17',
      value: '12000'
    }
  ]
}

// Encuentra el valor máximo
maxValue=Math.max(...objeto.resultados.map(x=>parseInt(x.value)))
// Filtra el objeto tal que los valores sean igual al máximo
result=objeto.resultados.filter(x=>x.value==maxValue)
// Imprime el resultado
console.log(result)
```